# create vertical menu like www.tokonita.com

Tags: javascript, css

i'm wondering how to create vertical menu like [www.tokonita.com](http://www.tokonita.com)

Can someone point me how to do it?Thanks..

Comment: Are you comfortable with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Comment: Are you a programmer?! This is NOT a web design forum.

Comment: well, javascript is still part of programming i guess... though handoyo can try doctype.com instead.

Comment: if it's useful, put a tick to it =)

Comment: Don't "questions" like these come across as "canihazachezburgr" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can find many examples at [DynamicDrive](http://dynamicdrive.com).

You got to very comfortable with JS+CSS+HTML aka DHTML.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to view the source of this site you pointed out and learn how exactly they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are using MooTools on that website.

You don't necessarily need any JavaScript library to something as simple as that, just absolutely position a div right next to the menu item and put whatever you want in the div.